# Can I override a previously cached 301 redirect?

Tags: http, browser

If I have a url, say `/resources/1234/original-title-of-resource`.

The id `1234` is the only significant part of the url, the title is there to make the url readable.

My app will permanently (301) redirect any incorrect spelling of the title to the correct version.

Given the following events:

1. User A updates the title so that the url becomes `/resources/1234/the-new-title`.
2. User B visits the original url and caches the 301
3. User A changes the name back to `/resources/1234/original-title-of-resource`
4. User B visits `/resources/1234/the-new-title`

Is this safe to do? Will the browser get stuck in a loop of cached redirects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Redirection 3xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-54) section of RFC 7231 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1):

> A client SHOULD detect and intervene in cyclical redirections (i.e., "infinite" redirection loops).
>
> Note: An earlier version of this specification recommended a maximum of five redirections ([RFC2068], Section 10.3). Content developers need to be aware that some clients might implement such a fixed limitation.

While you have no guarantee that it won't do an infinite loop, in practice with current browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Edge), they will detect the loop, fetch a new response from the server, if the server still gives a 301 loop, it will display an error message, if not, it will update the cache with the new 301.